# Sphere with constant velocity moving in stationary fluid.

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A sphere of radius a moves with constant velocity $U$ in a fluid otherwise at rest. How
far ahead of the sphere is there a disturbance of magnitude $1/20.U$? Show that the acceleration of a fluid particle at distance x ahead of the centre of the sphere is
$$3U^2(\frac{a^3}{x^4}-\frac{a^6}{x^7})$$

I think I've got that the potential function is 
$$-U \frac{a^3}{2r^2}\cos{\theta}$$
but i'm not sure how to go further to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that I agree with your potential function.  $v_r$ must go to zero at $r=a$, which it does not with your potential function.  Though I have to admit that [someone does agree with you](http://chemeng.iisc.ernet.in/kumaran/courses/TP_chapter10.pdf).  I prefer the function you can find [here](http://www.atm.damtp.cam.ac.uk/people/mem/FLUIDS-IB/irrot-rot.pdf), since it gives a correct $v_r$ at $r=a$:

$\Phi=U(r+\frac{a^3}{2r^2})\cos\theta$

Anyway, once you decide on your potential, $\Phi$, the first question involves just taking $v_r=\partial\Phi/\partial r$, setting $\theta=0$, and solving for where $v_r$ equals your given number.

For the second part, acceleration = $dv/dt = d (\partial\Phi/\partial r)/dt=dr/dt\cdot\partial^2\Phi/\partial r^2=$
$v\cdot\partial^2\Phi/\partial r^2=\partial\Phi/\partial r\cdot\partial^2\Phi/\partial r^2=1/2\cdot \partial_r((\partial_r\Phi)^2)$